# PerformSelector in a specific thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, nsthread, performselector

I own an application that sends files to a web server (images, texts, audios) of a simultaneous manner, not to weigh on the main thread, I thought I would distribute these operations between existing devices in the apple thread.

I saw in debug the xcode simulator have 5 thread, and I try to do this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(SendImages) onThread:1 withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
[self performSelector:@selector(SendText) onThread:2 withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
[self performSelector:@selector(SendAudio) onThread:3 withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

In this code I'm using 3 threads to do different functions, but I have two problems with this code:

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter
>   of type 'NSThread *'
>
> Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2;address=0x3)

How can I solve this problems? (ARC is disable in my project)

Comment: "existing devices in the apple thread"? Also if you bother to look at the reference you'll see that the `onThread` parameter wants an `NSThread *`, not an integer.

Comment: @trojanfoe, Ok I know only 1 code to put here:  [NSThread mainThread], but how I can select second thread or four thread?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` you need a reference to the `NSThread` object, not an integer (which presumably you think is an index into an array of threads?).

If you want to do these operations on a background thread you are best off using `NSInvocationOperation` and an `NSOperationQueue` and the OS will manage the background threading for you.

For example:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSOperationQueue *queue;

...

queue = [NSOperationQueue new];  
[queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:3]; 
NSInvocationOperation *operationImages = [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(SendImages) object:nil] autorelease];  
NSInvocationOperation *operationText = [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(SendText) object:nil] autorelease];  
NSInvocationOperation *operationAudio = [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(SendAudio) object:nil] autorelease];  
[queue addOperation:operationImages];  
[queue addOperation:operationText];  
[queue addOperation:operationAudio];
```

Comment: How the max concurrent operations per count NSOperationQueue can make?

Comment: Depends on the device. If you the `NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount` the OS will figure it out for you.